# How can I access FTP to centOS?

Tags: ftp, centos, ftp-client

I am newbie to CentOS. We have installed and configured CentOS. Now, facing one problem is that How can I access FTP from Windows machine to CentOS machine? Which kind of configuration I need to do in CentOS server? I heard about vsftpd, does that help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install ftp like vsftpd and then start service then you can ftp your centos machine from windows using any ftp client for example filezilla.

Install vsftpd with yum as

> yum install vsftpd

Start service vsftpd

> service vsftpd start

then make sure that port 21 is listening on your centos machine.

> netstat -an |grep 21

OUTPUT should like

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

You can also check with telnet from your windows cmd enter below command. yourIP replace with centos machine's IP

> telnet yourIP 21

Now you can FTP centos with ftp client (filezilla) or from browser.